# WordPress Media Manager cannot rename my images?

Tags: wordpress

[**Edit** > *I understand its the default behavior of WordPress Media Manager to do this and I'm seeking a workaround*]

I've found that if you rename an image using the WordPress Media Manager, it appears to rename the image, however, it only renames the "Title" of the image that you see in Media Manager. It does not, as I would expect it should, rename the actual filename of the image.

This is misleading in that I expect when I rename the image its actually renaming the file itself, not the "friendly name" that WordPress uses to display the image in media manager.

So if I "rename" an image in wordpress from say "MyImage.jpg" to "MyNewImage.jpg" and then try to link to MyNewImage.jpg, I will get a 404 error.

Is there are workaround or setting for this, or am i missing something?

Comment: not programming related, wrong forum

Answer (score 0):

What you're seeing is the behavior as it works.  It's debatable whether it *should* work a different way, but that's an issue for the WordPress folks.  I'd recommend the [WordPress support forum](http://wordpress.org/support/) or if you feel that it's a bug, you can [submit a WordPress bug report](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/).

Comment: Thanks ahockley, perhaps I should have clarified in my question that I am aware that this is how it works (Now that I've figured it out), however, I'm just asking if there is a workaround to get over the "default" behavior. I look to SO for expert assistance on wordpress and numerous other technologies, I'm aware of wordpress support forum, but they are nearly useless in terms of response diversity.